# Nuxt, Vuex data clears on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, nuxt.js, vuex

I have an app using Nuxt on the front-end. Since Nuxt is a SSR technology the data in vuex stores gets deleted after refreshing the browser. Is there a way to save and keep vuex data in browser storage (preferably **not** cookies) even after refreshing the browser?

Comment: local storage data never gets deleted on browser refresh. And also vuex don't save data on localStorage automatically.

Comment: Your Vue's state and the fact that Nuxt is SSR are not related anyhow. When you do refresh any regular VueJS app, the state will vanish so you're removing the whole data from the page (and therefore Vuex).

Answer (score 3):

We use [vuex-persist](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-persist) to save some store information in indexDB to provide offline feature (PWA) but you can use localstorage and cookies as well. Its pretty forward to use and also have an nuxt implementation:

```
// Inside - nuxt.config.js
export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vuex-persist', ssr: false }
  ]
}
```

```
// ~/plugins/vuex-persist.js
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist'

export default ({ store }) => {
  new VuexPersistence({
  /* your options */
    key: 'vuex', // The key to store the state on in the storage provider.
    storage: window.localStorage, // or window.sessionStorage or localForage 
  }).plugin(store);
}
```

Comment: You might run into render errors, since the client does render differently then the server, which is issued by the client side vuex persist

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save your Vuex state without any kind of browser storage. Depending on what you need to store, you could use:

- [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if it's some small information, some setting or alike
- make an API call to your backend and repopulate your Vuex store accordingly (best solution, especially if you stored some JWT token in your `localStorage`)
- [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), never used it but it's some kind of light database

Still, storing your whole Vuex state is not a thing to do in the browser for various reasons (security, performance, principle etc...).

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to kissu's answer.  You can use replaceState to restore a saved state.

But you probably shouldn't, you can create a bug that your user can't get out of by refreshing.  And that's really frustrating.

The pattern to do this is fairly simple.

First, in vuex, subscribe to all mutations

https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe

```js
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  console.log(mutation.type)
  console.log(mutation.payload)
})

// you may call unsubscribe to stop the subscription
unsubscribe()
```

Check which mutations you are interested in saving and store them in localStorage, or IndexDb or whatever you want.

On page load you need to check your storage solution for this data.  If it exists. call replaceState
https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#replacestate

```js
store.replaceState(state: Object) // give it an object structure matching your Vuex module state structure
```

And this is how you can save and reload state.